# LangChain AgentExecutor call() complains that one input key is expected, but got 2 when input is passed. Complains that input is missing when removed

Tags: typescript, openai-api, langchain

I am using LangChain Typescript (0.0.96) to build a simple chatbot that can answer questions. I am using an AgentExecutor that takes tools for looking up information from a DB and EntityMemory as the memory. Here is what the code looks like:

```
// Create memory input
const input = {"input": question};
// Load the relevant history using the entities used in the question and the conversation
relevantEntityHistory = await this.memory.loadMemoryVariables(input);

console.log('Relevant Entity History', relevantEntityHistory);
/**
* Relevant Entity History {
*  history: '',
*  entities: {
*    HTML: 'No current information known.',
*    AI: 'No current information known.',
*    JavaScript: 'No current information known.'
*  }
*}
*/

// Create the agent executor
if (!this.executor) {
   // Build the agent executor with options
   this.executor = await initializeAgentExecutorWithOptions(this.tools, this.model, {
       agentType: "chat-conversational-react-description",
       verbose: true,
       memory: this.memory,
    });
}

console.log("Executing with input: ", question);
// Executing with input:  Please create an HTML page with three columns. The left column will have a list of conversations the customer had with our AI chatbot. The middle column will contain all messages for a selected conversation and a text area for customers to send new messages. The right column will have a list of knowledge base sources that the chatbot can use to answer customer questions.

const result = await this.executor.call({ 
    input: question,
    chat_history: relevantEntityHistory.history,
});
```

The problem seems to be in the **input: question** property sent to the executor call method. The above code gives me this error:

> Error: One input key expected, but got 2

I tried removing the input and interestingly, it seems that it was able to start executing the chain but then it complained about "Missing value for input variable `input`"

```
[chain/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor] Entering Chain run with input: {
  "chat_history": [],
  "history": "",
  "entities": {
    "Human: \n\nOutput: NONE": "No current information known."
  }
}

[chain/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:LLMChain] Entering Chain run with input: {
  "chat_history": [],
  "history": "",
  "entities": {
    "Human: \n\nOutput: NONE": "No current information known."
  },
  "agent_scratchpad": [],
  "stop": [
    "Observation:"
  ]
}

[chain/error] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:LLMChain] [3ms] Chain run errored with error: "Missing value for input variable `input`"

[chain/error] [1:chain:AgentExecutor] [8ms] Chain run errored with error: "Missing value for input variable `input`"

    at C:\Users\Sheri\autodev\node_modules\langchain\dist\prompts\chat.cjs:224:27
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at ChatPromptTemplate.formatMessages (C:\Users\Sheri\autodev\node_modules\langchain\dist\prompts\chat.cjs:222:62)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ChatPromptTemplate.formatPromptValue (C:\Users\Sheri\autodev\node_modules\langchain\dist\prompts\chat.cjs:115:32)
    at async LLMChain._call (C:\Users\Sheri\autodev\node_modules\langchain\dist\chains\llm_chain.cjs:120:29)
    at async LLMChain.call (C:\Users\Sheri\autodev\node_modules\langchain\dist\chains\base.cjs:80:29)
    at async LLMChain.predict (C:\Users\Sheri\autodev\node_modules\langchain\dist\chains\llm_chain.cjs:139:24)
    at async ChatConversationalAgent._plan (C:\Users\Sheri\autodev\node_modules\langchain\dist\agents\agent.cjs:211:24)
    at async AgentExecutor._call (C:\Users\Sheri\autodev\node_modules\langchain\dist\agents\executor.cjs:88:28)
```

Any pointers as to what I am missing or how to properly pass the 'input' in my case would be really appreciated. Thanks!

---

**Quick Update**

I tried using the executor run() method instead of call(), although I am not entirely what the difference between them is (the Typescript documentation is still a little thin). Here is what this part of the code looks like:

```
const result = await this.executor.run({
    input: question,
});
```

But I still received, more or less, the same error

```
Error retrieving response from  as knowledge base using OpenAI: Error: Chain agent_executor expects multiple inputs, cannot use 'run'
    at AgentExecutor.run (C:\Users\Sheri\autodev\node_modules\langchain\dist\chains\base.cjs:53:19)
    at WebsiteBasedConversationAgent.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sheri\autodev\dist\services\agents\WebsiteBasedConversationAgent.js:99:48)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\Sheri\autodev\dist\services\agents\WebsiteBasedConversationAgent.js:5:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I also tried commenting the loadMemoryVariables() line in my code in case it is somehow causing the duplicate inputs but no dice

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem but ran with the AbortSignal object and the openai-functions agent.

You need to change from this:

```
const result = await this.executor.call({ 
    input: question,
    chat_history: relevantEntityHistory.history,
});
```

to this:

```
const history = relevantEntityHistory.history
const result = await this.executor.call({ 
    input: question,
    chat_history: history,
});
```

Hope it works for you!